# Check constraint for a condition in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

I'm trying to create a check constraint to prevent people from changing a `sales_status` to `3` unless the `progression_status` is `80`.

I thought it was

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
   ADD CONSTRAINT sales_status_cant_be_3_for_nonprogressed 
   CHECK (((sales_status = 3 ) or (progression_status < 80)))
```

however this is returning an error saying that some row violates it. When I run the query

```
select * from mytable where sales_status = 3 and progression_status < 80
```

I get no results as expected. Yet I can't seem to make the check constraint to work

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: I think constraint name is more than 32 characters. Preferably, read the `variable naming rules`.

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed: constraint names can be up to 63 characters in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i updated op

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, the error is because you have existing data that violates the constraint.  So, check if this is true in existing data:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not ( (sales_status = 3 ) or (progression_status < 80) );
```

Note that this assumes that the columns are not `null`. (`check` constraints and `where` treat `null` booleans differently.)

EDIT:

I think the logic you want is:

```
CHECK ((sales_status <> 3 ) or (progression_status >= 80));
```